# Gitlab: build docker container, then use it for compilation

Tags: docker, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

Heres my .gitlab-ci.yml

```
stages:
   - containerize
   - compile

build_image:
  image: docker
  stage: containerize
  script:
    - docker build -t compiler_image_v0 .

compile:
  image: compiler_image_v0
  stage: compile
  script:
    - make
  artifacts:
    when: on_success
    paths:
      - output/
    expire_in: 1 day
```

The `build_image` is running correctly, the image created is listed when using the `docker images` command on the machine with the runners. But the second job fails with the error:

> ERROR: Job failed: Error response from daemon: pull access denied for compiler_image_v0, repository does not exist or may require 'docker login' (executor_docker.go:168:1s)

What's going on?

This is my `Dockerfile`

```
FROM ubuntu:18.04

WORKDIR /app

# Ubuntu packages
RUN apt-get update
RUN DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive apt-get -y install apt-utils subversion g++ make cmake unzip
RUN DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive apt-get -y install libgtk2.*common libpango-1* libasound2* xserver-xorg
RUN DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive apt-get -y install cpio
RUN DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive apt-get -y install bash
RUN DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive apt-get -y install autoconf automake perl m4

# Intel Fortran compiler
RUN mkdir /intel
COPY parallel_studio_xe_2018_3_pro_for_docker.zip  /intel
RUN cd /intel && unzip /intel/parallel_studio_xe_2018_3_pro_for_docker.zip
RUN cd /intel/parallel_studio_xe_2018_3_pro_for_docker && ./install.sh --silent=custom_silent.cfg
RUN rm -rf /intel
```

Comment: Do you really want to execute the containerize stage on every build? Could you post your Dockerfile?

Comment: Let's assume I do need to execute the containerize stage on every build. I updated the question with the Dockerfile.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The stage compile tries to pull the image `compiler_image_v0`. This image exists only temporary in the docker container of the stage `containerize`. You have a container registry in your gitlab repository and can push the built image in the `containerize` stage and then pull it in the `compile` stage. Furthermore: You should provide a full name of your private gitlab registry. I think dockerhub is used per default.

You can change your `.gitlab.ci.yaml` to add the push command and use a fully named image:

```
stages:
   - containerize
   - compile

build_image:
  image: docker
  stage: containerize
  script:
    - docker build -t compiler_image_v0 .
    - docker push registry.gitlab.com/group-name/repo-name:compiler_image_v0

compile:
  image: registry.gitlab.com/group-name/repo-name:compiler_image_v0
  stage: compile
  script:
    - make
  artifacts:
    when: on_success
    paths:
      - output/
    expire_in: 1 day
```

This would overwrite the image on each build. But you could add some versioning.

Comment: Ok, thanks I'll go with that. But I'd like some clarification: you say that the image is only temporary, so why does it appear when I run `docker images` on the runner host?

Comment: I was not aware that the image remains on the host, so this is a wrong info I gave. But it really depends on the configuration of the host or when the host is reset. Do you manage the runner host yourself? I image that the hosts of the public runners are reset regularly.

Comment: As a sidenote: You might want to look into multi stage builds for docker. This could solve your problem, too: https://docs.docker.com/develop/develop-images/multistage-build/

Comment: If I may add: I would say do not use docker-in-docker if you can. I'm not fully aware of what Gitlab offers as runners when they aren't self hosted, but a shell executor would be better imho, rather than dind, although Gitlab tend to document a lot of things around it... Multistage builds are a cool feature too. Pushing the image is a way too. If you're in control of your runner's config, you might also consider looking at the [pull policy](https://docs.gitlab.com/runner/executors/docker.html#how-pull-policies-work)